# rss feeds list(free)

Tags: rss, feed

I need to have a complete list of feeds provided by all of sites or list of sites which have rss feeds on their site. Searched on google a lot, but couldn't find out how to get that list.

Comment: Sounds a bit like you want to download the internet ! :P

Comment: En.... 
Please tell us what the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll never be able to get a complete list of all RSS feeds on the Internet.  Such lists just do not exist.  Your best bet would be to see if any of the big RSS aggregators offer lists of feeds they know about - but that is commercially important information, so I doubt they'll be giving it away, and certainly not for free!

Answer (score 1):

You could use google:  Results 1 - 10 of about 3,880,000,000 for *.rss. (0.23 seconds)  Have fun